# Where do I find the log output from Bixby Developer Studio? Are there different levels of logging?

Tags: logging, bixby, bixbystudio

I’m logging using console.log but where do I see the log files? Do you support different log levels e.g. error, warning, debug etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs are viewable from the debug console. Open the debug console and expand functions and you will see your log output.

[image: Log Location]

There are multiple log levels available. console.log is at the info level

- console.debug - log a debug message
- console.info - log an info message (console.log is the same as this)
- console.warn - log a warning message
- console.error - log an error
- console.dir - alias for debug